# Why is it that after session_destroy() on page3.php and i go back to page1.php, session_start() is not working anymore?

Tags: php

After page3.php i go back to page1.php but i cant assign a new value to $_SESSION['answer'] anymore. i'm getting the error Undefined Index: answer

PAGE 1:

```
<?php

session_start();

$true_status = 'unchecked';
$false_status = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

 $_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];

$selected_radio = $_POST['answer'];


if ($selected_radio == 'true') {
$true_status = 'checked';

                }
else if ($selected_radio == 'false') {
$false_status = 'checked';



                    }
    }                   



?>

<body>

<FORM name ="form1" method ="post" action = 'page2.php'>

<h2>Q1. True or False?</h2>
<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='answer' value= 'true'
<?php echo $true_status; ?>
>TRUE

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='answer' value= 'false' 
<?php echo $false_status; ?>
>FALSE

<p>
<Input type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Next Page">


</FORM>
</body>
```

I'm just trying to display the value of $_SESSION['answer']

PAGE 2:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['answer'];

?>

<body>
<FORM name ="form3" method ="post" action ="page3.php">
<Input type = "Submit" name="Submit2" value="Next Page" >
</FORM>

</body>
```

PAGE 3:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['answer'];

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
?>

<body>


<FORM name ="form2" method ="post" action ="page1.php">

<Input type = "Submit" name="Submit3" value="TRY QUIZ AGAIN" >

</FORM>
</body>
```

Comment: that warning is for $_POST, not for $_SESSION

Comment: to elaborate on @Jack a little: page 3 which is posting back to page 1 does not have any input withe the `name` answer` so it's `$_POST['answer']` is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you code in `page3.php` have `Submit` type with name `Submit1` when code reach in this line

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
 $_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
}
```

its become `true` but you dont have any element have name like `answer`  thats way its error showing for fixing this problem in `page3.php` change name of `Submit1` to another name like `firstpage'.

**Edit**

since you in `page1` pass `form` to `page2` you have to add this line on top in `page2`

```
$_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer'];
```

[image]

Comment: i try changing it to Submit3 but still not working

Comment: tested its working !

Comment: tnx this help. its working now. i also remove the method="post" in the FORM on page3

Answer (score 1):

As the others have mentioned in their comments and answers:

The warning you get is because the $_POST doesn't contain the 'answer' key, because in page3.php the name of the input is "Submit1". The $_POST global variable is an array that contains values with the keys taken from the name property of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In short page 3 which is posting back to page 1 does not have any input with the name answer so it's `$_POST['answer']` is not defined.

If you would like to carry over the "answer" from page 3 back to page 1, one option would be to use a hidden input, like so:

1. (copy and paste this code onto the line **before** `$_SESSION = array();` on page 3) `$stored_answer = $_SESSION['answer'];`
2. (and copy and paste this code onto the line ***before*** `</FORM>` also on page 3) `<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?=$stored_answer?>"/>`.

This will preserve your "answer" as you move from page3 back to page 1.

Comment: why store it when he want new value in `page1`?

Comment: hence my preface "**If** you would like to carry...". I could easily think of a scenario where he would want the user to be able to see their previous/incorrect answer when they are re-trying...

Comment: **again** still its handle this stuff before going to page he gonna create get new value and incorrect one stay in `page3`

Comment: i tried this but the error now shows in page1, before its in page2 and 3

Comment: @PaulWalker - can you post your updated code?

Comment: pls check the edited version on top, i tried it again. there is no error this time but it's not displaying any value on page2 and 3.

Comment: that's because on page 1 you are not only checking for `$_POST['answer']` but you are also checking to see if `isset($_POST['Submit1'])` before you store the answer in the session.
I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do here but just in the interest of confirming that that is indeed the issue - just change that line on page 1 to `if (isset($_POST['answer']))`... makes sense?

Comment: tnx. i add $_SESSION['answer'] = $_POST['answer']; on page2 like what @Hosseini said and its working now. i'm just trying to learn about session_start(), $_SESSION.